# Autoloading of classes of a local TYPO3 extension

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-10.x

In my following `composer.json` I am requiring extensions, which are in the same Git repository as the whole project. So I add in the `repositories` section and later I do `composer req vendor/site_package:@dev` in order to require my local extension.

Now I realized, that some classes of the extension are not autoloaded.

Do I need to additional add the `autoload` part as shown below in the `composer.json` of the project?

```
{
    "name": "site-package",
    "description": "Base composer.json",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "./packages/*"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "typo3/cms-backend": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-belog": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-beuser": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-core": "^10.4",
        ...
        "vendor/site_package": "@dev",
        "georgringer/news": "^8",
        ...
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "public/typo3conf/ext/site_package/Classes"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Vendor\\SitePackage\\": "public/typo3conf/ext/site_package/Classes"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "typo3/cms": {
            "root-dir": "public",
            "web-dir": "public"
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "vendor",
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "typo3-cms-scripts": [
            "typo3cms install:generatepackagestates",
            "typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "@typo3-cms-scripts"
        ]
    }
}
```

In `ext:site_package` I have the following autoload section as well:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Vendor\\SitePackage\\": "Classes",
    }
},
```

Do I need both? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never mix those 2 `composer.json`.

As you already follow the approach of having a directory `packages` (which is a good thing) each extension inside there needs an own `composer.json` file which of course also needs a section

```json
"psr-4": {
   "Vendor\\MyExt\\": "Classes"
}
```

By requiring this package, this autoload information will be used.

---

If you would still have the custom extension inside `typo3conf/ext/my_ext`, that `composer.json`file would **not** be taken into account and you need something like

```json
"psr-4": {
   "Vendor\\MyExt\\": "typo3conf/ext/myext/Classes"
}
```

Comment: That's what I expected too, all required extensions in `packages` will be autoloaded from their `composer.json`. Interesting part is, that most classes are available (e.g. custom ViewHelpers), but a slot class with namespace `Vendor\MyExt\Slot` is not found (`1245673367 TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\SignalSlot\Exception\InvalidSlotException: The given class "Vendor\MyExt\Slot\MySlot" is not a registered object.`). As soon as I add the `classmap` section in the projects composer.json, the class is found. The `psr-4` section the projects composer.json is not needed... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: One more information on that: The `psr-4` part in `autoload` of the projects composer.json does not help either. Just the `classmap` fixes my problem.

Comment: are you sure that the slot follows the psr4 guidelines?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I didn't follow the psr-4 guidelines. The namespace was `Vendor\MyExt\Slot\MySlot` but the folder is named `Classes/Slots/`. After changing the namespace to `Vendor\MyExt\Slots\MySlot` it is working. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The `autoload` part is only needed in your site package `composer.json`. It's not necessary to put it also in the `composer.json` in your root folder.

Please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ComposerJson/Index.html) how the `composer.json` of your site package should look like.

If you still have problems with autoloading, try `composer dump-autoload` or remove the extension and require it again. And make sure to check the upper-/lowercase of your namespace. It's case sensitive. If you change that after you required the site package, you need to remove and require the package again.

Comment: That's what I expected too. See my comment at Georg Ringers answer.

Comment: By the way: The correct call to dump autoloading is `composer dump-autoload`. I can't edit you answer, since I would change less than 6 chars ;-)